# How do I reference a variable (a picker view value) from one view controller in another view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, class

I am trying to take these variables from one of my view controller's swift file:

```
 //global
let choice1Box1 = drivingGear[chooseDrivingGear.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
let choice2Box1 = drivingGear[chooseDrivenGear1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
```

This is whats being done to the variables in the original class:

```
@IBAction func showResultBox1(_ sender: Any) {

        let choice1Box1 = self.drivingGear[self.chooseDrivingGear.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        let choice2Box1 = self.drivingGear[self.chooseDrivenGear1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        if let intVal1 = Double(choice1Box1), let intVal2 = Double(choice2Box1) {
            result = intVal2 / intVal1

            let newLabel = String(result)
            resultBox1.setTitle(newLabel, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can pass data from one VC to another VC, by using `Delegate` and also you can use prepare(forSegue:) method. https://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/

Comment: Have added the answer in it, Please look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this:

Once you have picked the value from the pickerView. Pass it like this.

**For Eg. You need to pass a String to next VC:**

**In SecondVC:** Declare a value at top like this:

```
var strFromPreviousVC:String = String()
```

**In First VC:** Send the Value like this:

```
let objSecondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondVC
objSecondVC.strFromPreviousVC = "your selected String here"
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objSecondVC, animated: true)
```

And yes its done, it will be passed to SecondVc and you can use the value like `print(strFromPreviousVC)` in SecondVc

Hope it helps.

Comment: In addition you can use delegate

Comment: @Brkr I agree with  you, but delegates would be troublesome for Newbie's.

Comment: You are absolutely right. i gave positive vote for your answer.

Comment: Really appreciated that buddy.